# Is there a way in Batch to stop/log if PSCP fails to transfer a file?

Tags: batch-file, pscp

The line for PSCP I am using is

```
pscp -scp -2 -pw %PDUPW% %curfileloc%\devices\%PDUName%\%PDUName%p15.p15 %PDUUser%@%PDUIP%:/ssl/%PDUName%.p15
```

What I am looking to do is if the file fails to upload to write to some log file which units the upload failed to

Comment: I removed your PowerShell references, because you clearly were showing non PowerShell code. This site is not here to tell you how to perform tasks, it is for help to fix a single and specific issue with your submitted programming code. As you have not submitted non working code, your question is not on topic for this particular site.